# Confusion over semantics behind ∃-elimination

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

$\exists-$ states that: if $\Sigma, A(u) \vdash B$ where u occurs nowhere else, then $\Sigma, \exists x A(x) \vdash B$.

Why does this translate to $\exists$ and not $\forall$? Intuitively, $A(u)$ where $u$ occurs nowhere else should mean that $u$ can be any arbitrary thing, so shouldn't $\Sigma, A(u) \vdash B$ be valid for any conceivable $u$ (a.k.a, all $x$) meaning $\Sigma, \exists xA(x) \vdash B$?

This is giving me trouble mostly because of the below theorem I've already learned:

[image]

Why is it that in this case $A(u)$ can translate in to a "for all" while in $\exists-$ it only gives us "there exists"? In both cases $u$ is arbitrary, so it should refer to anything$-$"for all"$-$in my  head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term $u$ is arbitrary yes, but what isn't arbitrary is the fact that we have a derivation $\Sigma, A(u) \vdash B$.

What does it mean to have $\Sigma, A(u) \vdash B$? It means that, assuming $\Sigma$ and $A(u)$ (for some particular $u$), we can prove $B$. Moreover, since $u$ doesn't appear anywhere else, it can't be a "proper" part of the proof: all that is necessary to prove $B$ is that $A(x)$ is true for *some* x. The $\exists- $ says precisely this, that we don't care about the *specific* $u$ that satisfies $A(x)$, only that there is something which satisfies it.

On the other hand, suppose we can prove $A(u)$ from $\Sigma$ without assuming $u$. This means that the proof of $A(u)$ can't really "depend" on $u$, so we should be able to prove $A(x)$ for any $x$. And this is what the $\forall +$ rule says.

Comment: Great answer! +1. Just a remark: I wouldn't say that $\Sigma, A(u) \vdash B$ means that "assuming $Σ$ and $A(u)$ (for _some_ particular $u$), we can prove $B$". I would say that  "assuming $Σ$ and $A(u)$ (for _any_  generic $u$), we can prove $B$", i.e. that, "given any generic $u$, assuming $Σ$ and $A(u)$ we can prove $B$" (here by _generic_ I mean that it does not occur in $\Sigma$). Said differently, we are talking about the fact $\forall u (A(u) \to B)$ where $u$ does not occur in $B$ is the equivalent to $\exists u A(u) \to B$.

Comment: In categorical terms, entailment can be seen as a bifunctor _contravariant_ on the left argument and _covariant_ on the right argument. The meaning of the sentence I'm talking about depends on where you logically place the expression "for some particular $u$". Of course, natural language is not well conceived for this kind of subtleties, and it is difficult to avoid ambiguities, especially when we are using a language that is not our mother tongue (as in my case).

Answer (score 2):

> Intuitively, $A(u)$ where $u$ occurs nowhere else should mean that $u$ can be any arbitrary thing.

No, $u$ is **not** arbitrary.

"Arbitrary" means: whatever term $u$ we may choose...

This is not so: [we have to choose a “fresh” term, in the sense of having no other occurrences in the derivation](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7).

We have (as per the title of your question) to consider the semantics.

With $(\forall \text I)$ rule we may, under the condition that $u$ is "fresh", derive from $A(u)$ the "generalization" $\forall x A(x)$.

Here **every** possible choice of a term $u$ not already used will do, and this is consistent with the intuitive meaning of the rule: if $A$ holds of an "object" $u$ whatever, then it holds of every "object".

A simple arithmetical example is: we have proved $\mathsf {PA} \vdash (x \ge 0)$, where $\mathsf {PA}$ is the collection of Peano's axioms.

Then we may apply $(\forall \text I)$ to conclude with: $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \forall x(x \ge 0)$.

Consider now the formula $\exists x (x > 0)$.

If we want to use it in a proof with $(\exists \text E)$ rule, we have to choose a suitable term $u$ for the assumption $(u > 0)$: the formula $\exists x (x > 0)$ says there must be (at least) one.

But we cannot choose an "arbitrary" term, i.e. a term whatever: for $u=0$ we get $(0 > 0)$, which is false.